# How do I get a list of the history of all the vim commands I ran?

Tags: vim

I'm aware that much like a bash prompt in Vim you can press `:` and get a list of all the history commands by pressing up and down.

But is there a way to export this command history into a buffer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`:history` will show you a history of your commands.

**Edit:**

In normal mode, `q:` will open your history in a new buffer.

Comment: Can I load it into a new buffer?

Comment: This is a command-line window. If you use `<CR>`, for example, it will execute the current line command. However, you can yank lines around and put them in another buffer.

Comment: If you want a "real" buffer, not the special command-line window, use `:redir` together with `:history`, and paste the captured text into a `:new` buffer.

Answer (score 2):

you can check all the commands by looking into .viminfo in your home folder or `:history` inside  vim

Comment: is it called _viminfo in Windows??